# HTML in XML export issues in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, xml, metadata, arccatalog

I have some metadata saved using the ArcCatalog metadata editor.  The abstract element allows you to use html formatting.  When you export the metadata to xml the formatting is stripped out and the text is returned as a single line of text with newlines removed.

Is there a way to programmtically access these elements from Python and retain formatting and newlines.

Ideally this would be as an XML document.